# Arzela-Ascoli in proper metric space.

Tags: geometric-group-theory

In the book by Bridson and Haefliger http://www.math.bgu.ac.il/~barakw/rigidity/bh.pdf page 145. lemma 8.28 To prove part 2 of the lemma that is 
The natural map for $G_{x_0}\rightarrow Ends(X)$ is surjective. They use Arzela-Ascoli theorem for which the the image space need to be compact. But only assume X is  a proper metric space. For a proper ray $r:[0,\infty)\rightarrow X$ the image might not be compact. 
Can anyone please explain ?

Comment: I do not know the context, but you can use uniform convergence on compacts for such maps together with diagonal subsequence arguments.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I missed the fact that convergence on compact set.